# is_uploaded_file function worked in linux But not in Windows

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

**Code**

```
if(is_array($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['photography_attachment'])) {
      if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photography_attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
        $fileName = $_FILES["photography_attachment"]["name"]; // The file name
        $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["photography_attachment"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
        $fileType = $_FILES["photography_attachment"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
        $fileSize = $_FILES["photography_attachment"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
        $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["photography_attachment"]["error"]; // 0 = false | 1 = true
        $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
        $fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension

        if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
          $error = $error."<p>Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.</p>";
        } else if($fileSize > 10485760) { // if file size is larger than 2 Megabytes
          $error = $error."<p><span>Your file was larger than</span> 10 <span>Megabytes in size</span>.</p>";
          unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
        } else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$/i", $fileName) ) {
          // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types
          $error = $error."<p>Your file was not .gif, .jpg, .png</p>";
          unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
        } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
          $error = $error."<p>An error occured while processing the file. Try again.</p>";
        }
     }else{ $error = "Please try again !!!"; }
  }else{ $error = "Attachment field cannot be blank!"; }
```

Always goto "Please try again !!!" else while  uploading image in windows, but it worked well in linux system.

Can you please any one help me for this issue?

Comment: The above code doesn't do anything with the uploaded file if the logic succeeds?!

Comment: $_FILES response =>     [photography_attachment] => Array
        (
            [name] => ttest.jpg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

Comment: @AD7six I fixed my issues using below answers (Richard answers)

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar cool (if true, which seems unlikely) - not helpful for you to have pasted a different and unrelated error in comments then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows platforms you musst replace inside the file path the "\" with an "/"

Like this:

```
$file = str_replace ("\\", "/", $_FILES['photography_attachment']['tmp_name']);
if(is_uploaded_file($file)) {
   [...]
}
```

Or use the php build in method, for all systems:

```
$file = realpath($_FILES['photography_attachment']['tmp_name']);
if(is_uploaded_file($file)) {
   [...]
}
```